не получается вывести M_PI (C++)
#include <cmath>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define M_PI
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cout << M_PI;
  return 0;
}

/*подчеркиевает ; красной линией после M_PI и пишет,
 что ошибка C2059. Что делать?*/


вместо #define M_PI надо бы #include <cmath> как я понимаю. Иначе ты просто дефайнишь пустой M_PI

ой (у меня это было, в первой строчке, видимо, не все скопировала(тут можно это отредактировать(?)). Но и с подключением cmath не работает)

Так #define M_PI убрали?

Ошибка при использовании M_PI
